# Invalid String Length While using Javascript Objects and Functions

Tags: javascript, html, object

I am trying to make a function that I can put JavaScript objects into in order to not re-use html code over and over again.

I have two objects that look like this:

```
var TannerTrailGrandCanyon = {
  name: "Tanner Trail Grand Canyon",
  lat: 36.0326,
  long: -111.8525,
  type: "backpacking", 
  //Title then link
  seekAdventure: ['22 Hours of Driving, 1.5 Days of Snowshoeing, Yosemite National Park!','https://www.seekadventure.net/d/79-22-hours-of-driving-1-5-days-of-snowshoeing-yosemite-nationa'],
  blogs: []
};

var BadgerPass = {
  name: "Badger Pass - Yosemite",
  lat: 36.0326,
  long: -111.8525,
  type: "backpacking", 
  //Title then link
  seekAdventure: ['22 Hours of Driving, 1.5 Days of Snowshoeing, Yosemite National Park!','https://www.seekadventure.net/d/79-22-hours-of-driving-1-5-days-of-snowshoeing-yosemite-nationa'],
  blogs: ['Snowshoeing to Dewey Point in Yosemite - Socal Hiker','https://socalhiker.net/snowshoeing-to-dewey-point-in-yosemite/']
};
```

And they are then put into an array:

```
markers1 = [
  TannerTrailGrandCanyon,
  BadgerPass
];
```

Which I then use to put points on a google map.

Then I created a function to build html code that would go into the Google Map pop up bubble:

```
//put pop up bubble html together 
function BuildBubbleHTML(hike){
    html = "";
    html = html +'<h3>'  + hike.hikename + '</h3>';

    //If Seek Adventure Links Exist
    if(hike.seekAdventure.length > 0){
        seekAdventureHTML = '<p>Seek Adventure Links</p>';
        seekAdventureHTML = seekAdventureHTML + '<ul>'
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < hike.seekAdventure.length; i+2) { 
            seekAdventureHTML = seekAdventureHTML + '<li>';
            seekAdventureHTML = seekAdventureHTML + '<a href="' + hike.seekAdventure[i+1] + '">';
            seekAdventureHTML = seekAdventureHTML + hike.seekAdventure[i] + '</a></li>';
        } 
        seekAdventureHTML = seekAdventureHTML + '</ul>';
        html = html + seekAdventureHTML;
    }

    //If Blog Links Exist
    if(hike.blogs.length > 0){
        blogHTML = '<p>Blog Links</p>';
        blogHTML = blogHTML + '<ul>'
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < hike.blogs.length; i+2) { 
            blogHTML = blogHTML + '<li>';
            blogHTML = blogHTML + '<a href="' + hike.blogs[i+1] + '">';
            blogHTML = blogHTML + hike.blogs[i] + '</a></li>';
        } 
        blogHTML = blogHTML + '</ul>';
        html = html + blogHTML;
    }


    return html;
};
```

When I execute the code I get this error:

> mapCode.js:250 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid string length

The issue is on this line: `seekAdventureHTML = seekAdventureHTML + '<a href="' + hike.seekAdventure[i+1] + '">';`

I thought maybe it couldn't grab the i+1 before in the next line grabing the i but I swapped both and that still didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo here:

```
        for (i = 0; i < hike.seekAdventure.length; i+2) {
```

I'm assuming you meant `i++` (or possibly `i+=2`), not `i+2`. The value of i never changes, the loop is infinite and keeps adding to string - the script simply runs out of RAM.

Comment: Ooooo, I was trying to increase i by two instead of one each round through.... Doesn't i++ only increase by one?

Comment: So it should be `i+=2`.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly and I learned something new today!

Comment: One nitpick: the script doesn't run out of RAM. It runs until it hits the maximum (browser-dependent) string length. Hence the RangeError.